# How to test if a Ruby script is running via Bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler

In a Ruby script, is there a way to test if the current process has been launched via Bundler - i.e. via bundle exec or a binstub?

Comment: You could test for the existence of Bundler environment variables, such as `BUNDLE_GEMFILE`, perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could check `defined?(Bundler)`, but that will also be present if you `require 'bundler'` without having run `bundle exec`.

When you run inside `bundle exec`, there are a few `ENV` variables present that aren't otherwise. Notably, `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` and `BUNDLE_BIN_PATH`.

There are some more details in the `Environment Modifications` section of the [bundle exec docs](http://bundler.io/v1.10/man/bundle-exec.1.html).

Comment: Thanks, sniffing for ENV["BUNDLE_BIN_PATH"] worked perfect.

Comment: Word of caution: Once bundler has run once, the ENV keeps being set. So this only works on "fresh" terminals.